# jQuery script not working in woocommerce_cart_item_removed hook

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to run a javascript function after product is removed from the cart, but not working... I am using the function below

```
function action_woocommerce_remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key, $instance ) {
    ?>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        alert('removed');
        $('#cart_ifram').attr('src','<?php echo home_url(); ?>/cart/');
    });
    </script>
    <?php
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed', 'action_woocommerce_remove_cart_item', 10, 2 );
```

I have also tried woocommerce_cart_item_removed hook but it didn't worked for me. Also woocommerce updated cart hook works when an item is added to cart but not in my case... Thanks for help...

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please update.

Comment: Sorry but I think first line of my question explains what I'm asking about

Comment: I'm trying to run a function after a product is removed from cart..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To get jQuery working with Wordpress you need to use **`jQuery`** instead of shortland **`$`** at the begining, this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    alert('removed');
    $('#cart_ifram').attr('src','<?php echo home_url(); ?>/cart/');
});
```

… or …

```
(function($){
    alert('removed');
    $('#cart_ifram').attr('src','<?php echo home_url(); ?>/cart/');
})(jQuery);
```

2) You are using the correct hook, **but Javascript/jQuery don't seem to work in it**. Try this code and you will see that **you get a custom notice when removing a cart item**:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed', 'action_woocommerce_remove_cart_item', 10, 2 );
function action_woocommerce_remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key, $instance ) {

    // Displaying a custom notice
    wc_add_notice( 'ITEM REMOVED', 'error' );

    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            alert('Item removed');
            console.log('Item removed');
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

On cart page, there is a lot of WooCommerce javascript events that are certainly killing your custom made jQuery process, so is going to be complicated to get it work.

Comment: thanks for the help... as you mentioned in the answer wc_add_notice is working fine... but still my function is not working I used the function according to your guidelines but still no success... :( I simply need to refresh or reload the iframe.. is there any other possibility to do that..

Comment: I have also tried this...
`document.getElementById(cart_ifram).contentDocument.location.reload(true);`

Comment: @habib I can't help more than that for the moment…

Comment: ok thanks for the help, I 'm trying to find a solution.. if I got some solution, I will post here..